# Python Pandas: Construct a DataFrame with MultiIndex and Dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have dict that I would like to turn into a DataFrame with MultiIndex.
The dict is:

```
dikt = {'bloomberg': Timestamp('2009-01-26 10:00:00'),
 'investingcom': Timestamp('2009-01-01 09:00:00')}
```

I construct a MultiIndex such as follow:

```
MI= MultiIndex(levels=[['Existing Home Sales MoM'], ['investingcom', 'bloomberg']],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]],
           names=['indicator', 'source'])
```

Then a DataFrame as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = MI, columns=["datetime"],data =np.full((2,1),np.NaN))
```

Then lastly I fill the df with data stored in a dict such :

```
for key in ['indicator', 'source']:
    df.loc[('Existing Home Sales MoM',key), "datetime"] = dikt[key]
```

and get the expected result:

[image]

But would there be a more concise way of doing so by passing the `dikt` directly into the construction of the df such as

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = MI, columns=["datetime"],data =dikt)
```

so as to combine the 2 last steps in 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a datframe from a dictionary using [`from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dikt, orient='index')

                               0
bloomberg    2009-01-26 10:00:00
investingcom 2009-01-01 09:00:00
```

You can chain the column and index definitions to get the result you're after in 1 step:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dikt, orient='index') \
            .rename(columns={0: 'datetime'}) \
            .set_index(MI)
```